# Добавление товара из каталога в сделку битрикс24

Tags: php, битрикс, битрикс24, crm

Задача: добавить товар в сделку из каталога товаров. Товар добавляется, но поле цена всегда 0, а если убрать задание цены 'PRICE' => 111, то товар вообще не добавляется.

```
\Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule('crm');
\CCrmProductRow::Add(['OWNER_TYPE' => 'D', 'OWNER_ID' => 340, 'PRODUCT_ID' => 854, 'QUANTITY' => 1, 'PRICE' => 111, 'MEASURE_CODE' => 796, 'CURRENCY_ID' => 'RUB']);
```

Comment: попробуйте сделать значение 'PRICE' => '111'

Comment: @V.Baryshev Пробовал, не то

Comment: 'CURRENCY_ID' => 'RUB'] т очно "RUB"? вроде как ID)

Comment: @V.Baryshev В исходниках битрикса этот параметр именно RUB

Comment: ниже пример Добавления товара в каталог. А мне нужно добавить в сделку.

<?php 
if (\Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule('crm')) 
{ 
    $pid = CCrmProduct::add(array( 
        'NAME' => 'Товар в базе', 
        'QUANTITY' => 1, 
        'PRICE' => 100, 
        'MEASURE_CODE' => 796, 
        'CURRENCY_ID' => 'RUB', 
    )); 
    if ($pid) 
    { 
        $rows = array(); 
        $rows[] = array( 
            'PRODUCT_ID' => $pid, 
            'QUANTITY' => 1, 
        ); 
        CCrmProductRow::SaveRows('D', 10, $rows); 
    } 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я разобрался, там необходимо было добавить еще 'PRICE_NETTO', 'PRICE_BRUTTO', 'PRICE_EXCLUSIVE'. В коде ниже я сначала читаю товар, а потом подставляю соответствующие значения в добавленный товар в СРМ.

```
    \Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule('Catalog');
\Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule('crm');
\CCrmProductRow::DeleteByOwner('D', {=Document:ID});
$arr=CCatalogProduct::GetByIDEx(854); //854 - ID товара
if($tax=CCatalogVat::GetByID(2)->fetch()) 
{ \CCrmProductRow::Add(['OWNER_TYPE' => 'D', 'OWNER_ID' => {=Document:ID}, 'PRODUCT_ID' => 854, 'DISCOUNT_RATE' => '', 'DISCOUNT_SUM' => '', 'TAX_RATE' => $tax['RATE'], 'TAX_INCLUDED' => 'N', 'QUANTITY' => 1, 'PRICE' => '', 'PRICE_NETTO' => $arr['PRICES'][1]['PRICE'], 'PRICE_BRUTTO' => '', 'PRICE_EXCLUSIVE' => $arr['PRICES'][1]['PRICE'], 'MEASURE_CODE' => 796, 'CURRENCY_ID' => RUB]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rows[] = [
                'PRODUCT_ID' => 30, //id товара
                'QUANTITY' => 1, //количество
                'PRICE' => 1000, //цена
            ];
$res = CCrmProductRow::SaveRows('D', $dealID, $rows); //"D" - сделка, "L" - Лид
```